# tic tac toe with numbers in python

Tags: python

I have a H.W and this is it 
Tic-Tac-Toe with numbers. A board of 3 x 3 is displayed and player 1 takes odd numbers 1,
3, 5, 7, 9 and player 2 takes even numbers 0, 2, 4, 6, 8. Players take turns to write their
numbers. Odd numbers start. Use each number only once. The first person to complete a line
that adds up to 15 is the winner. The line can have both odd and even numbers
.

and i made till here

```
board = [0,1,2,
         3,4,5,
         6,7,8]


def tic_tac_toe ():

 print ('|' ,board[0],'|',board[1] ,'|', board[2],'|')

 print ('--------------------')

 print ('|' ,board[3],'|',board[4] ,'|', board[5],'|')

 print ('--------------------')

 print ('|' ,board[6],'|',board[7] ,'|', board[8],'|')


def move(x1,x2):

 board[x2] = x1

     tic_tac_toe()



def odd (x):

    while  (x%2==0):

        x = int(input ('enter an odd number')

        move(x,x2)

    if (x%2!=0):

        move (x ,x2)        



def even (x) :

     while  (x%2!=0):

        x = int(input ('enter an even number')

        move(x,x2)


     if (x%2==0):

        move (x ,x2)        


def winner ():

    if (board[0]+board [1]+board[2]==15 or

        board[0]+board [3]+board[6]==15 or

        board[1]+board [4]+board[7]==15 or

        board[3]+board [4]+board[5]==15 or

        board[2]+board [5]+board[8]==15 or

        board[6]+board [7]+board[8]==15):

        print ('you are the winner')

def turn(s):

    print ('its '+ s +' turn')

    x = int (input ('enter the number: '))
    x1 = int (input ('enter the places number: '))            


print('Tic Tac Toe')

print ('player A should enter even numbers only'+' and player B should enter odd 
numbers only')

print ('the player with the ood numbers start')

tic_tac_toe ()

while (true):

    turn(B)

    odd(x1)
    break
```

my problem now that I want to make a function that checks if there is a winner every time a player enters a number and I want it to know the difference between the numbers that have been entered and the number that is already there (the numbers of the positions)
 and I'm really new to programming so please excuse me if the code has a lot of mistakes

Comment: I'll give you a hint about knowing if a number is already on the board or not, You can use the `in` keyword. E.g. `if number in board: print "Number [{}] has already been used.".format(number)`

Comment: to answer your question, after the function that swaps turns (I suppose it's `turn(s)`, you should place the `winner()` function. Now, you should have a variable like `player = 'a'` that, after a turn and having checked if there's a winner, swaps to the other player. Also, in `odd()` and `even()`, you change the board even if the number inputted is not valid, because you wrote an extra `move(x, x2)` function before the `if(x%2 ...` conditions.

Comment: also nothing is going to change because the variables inputted in `turn(s)` are not returned so they're unknown in the `odd()` and `even()` functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

I added a board log array to monitor which positions contain user input, and then in the winner function cross reference said array to validate win criteria

```
board = [0,1,2,
     3,4,5,
     6,7,8]
boardLog = [0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0]

player = 'a' #with this we'll know which player's turn it is

def tic_tac_toe ():
    print ('|' ,board[0],'|',board[1] ,'|', board[2],'|')
    print ('--------------------')
    print ('|' ,board[3],'|',board[4] ,'|', board[5],'|')
    print ('--------------------')
    print ('|' ,board[6],'|',board[7] ,'|', board[8],'|')

def move(x1,x2):
    board[x2] = x1
    boardLog[x2] = 1
    tic_tac_toe()

def odd (x, x2):
    while  (x%2==0):
        x = int(input ('enter an odd number'))
    #Nothing here because if we get out of the while is because it's a valid number (we're not checking numbers out of range or anything)
    move (x ,x2)      

def even (x ,x2) :
    while  (x%2!=0):
        x = int(input ('enter an even number'))
    #Same here
    move (x ,x2)        

def winner():
    if (boardLog[0] + boardLog[1] + boardLog[2] == 3):
      if (board[0]+board [1]+board[2]==15):
          print ('you are the winner')
          return True
    if (boardLog[0] + boardLog[3] + boardLog[6] == 3):
      if (board[0]+board [3]+board[6]==15):
          print ('you are the winner')
          return True
    if (boardLog[1] + boardLog[4] + boardLog[7] == 3):
      if (board[1]+board [4]+board[7]==15):
          print ('you are the winner')
          return True
    if (boardLog[3] + boardLog[4] + boardLog[5] == 3):
      if (board[3]+board [4]+board[5]==15):
          print ('you are the winner')
          return True
    if (boardLog[2] + boardLog[5] + boardLog[8] == 3):
      if (board[2]+board [5]+board[8]==15):
          print ('you are the winner')
          return True
    if (boardLog[6] + boardLog[7] + boardLog[8] == 3):
      if (board[6]+board [7]+board[8]==15):
          print ('you are the winner')
          return True

    else: return False

def turn(s):
    print ('its '+ s +' turn')
    x = int (input ('enter the number: '))
    x1 = int (input ('enter the places number: '))
    if player == 'a':
        even(x, x1)
    else: odd(x, x1)          

print('Tic Tac Toe')
print ('player A should enter even numbers only'+' and player B should enter odd numbers only')
print ('the player with the ood numbers start')
tic_tac_toe ()
while (True):
    turn(player)
    if winner(): break
    else:
        if player == 'a': player = 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this close to what you want. Notice the comments. Also know that I haven't tested this, I just corrected your code a little. Any questions, feel free to ask.

```
board = [0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0]
player = 'a' #with this we'll know which player's turn it is

def tic_tac_toe ():
    print ('|' ,board[0],'|',board[1] ,'|', board[2],'|')
    print ('--------------------')
    print ('|' ,board[3],'|',board[4] ,'|', board[5],'|')
    print ('--------------------')
    print ('|' ,board[6],'|',board[7] ,'|', board[8],'|')

def move(x1,x2):
    board[x2] = x1
    tic_tac_toe()

def odd (x, x2):
    while  (x%2==0):
        x = int(input ('enter an odd number'))
    #Nothing here because if we get out of the while is because it's a valid number (we're not checking numbers out of range or anything)
    move (x ,x2)      

def even (x ,x2) :
    while  (x%2!=0):
        x = int(input ('enter an even number'))
    #Same here
    move (x ,x2)        

def winner ():
    if (board[0]+board [1]+board[2]==15 or
        board[0]+board [3]+board[6]==15 or
        board[1]+board [4]+board[7]==15 or
        board[3]+board [4]+board[5]==15 or
        board[2]+board [5]+board[8]==15 or
        board[6]+board [7]+board[8]==15):
        print ('you are the winner')
        return true #To know if we need to stop the game
    else: return false

def turn(s):
    print ('its '+ s +' turn')
    x = int (input ('enter the number: '))
    x1 = int (input ('enter the places number: '))
    if player == 'a':
        even(x, x1)
    else: odd(x, x1)          

print('Tic Tac Toe')
print ('player A should enter even numbers only'+' and player B should enter odd numbers only')
print ('the player with the ood numbers start')
tic_tac_toe ()
while (true):
    turn(player)
    if winner(): break
    else:
        if player == 'a': player = 'b'
        else: player = 'a'
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped me a lot 
but I'm still finding a problem with the winner function 
because it counts the places number not only the numbers that entered by the players

Comment: well that's how you declared the initial matrix, I thought you wanted it to start with values `[0, 1, 2, 3, ... ]`